# Redirecting all domain aliases to one with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a few domain aliases, while I only want one of them to be actually used.
At the moment, I have two domains installed,

To redirect I'd like to use htaccess.

My domains currently work like so:

www.domain.com/index.html - Main domain's home page

www.secondDomain.com/index.html - Displays exactly the same home page as the main domain, but I want it to automatically rename the url to www.domain.com/index.html when it's used.

Thanks!

Comment: Also the same issue you can see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19876329/htaccess-redirect-alias-to-main-domain - this solution works for me

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is a simple matter of matching `%{HTTP_HOST}` not equal to `www.domain.com` and redirecting that to the canonical domain.

```
RewriteEngine On
# If the hostname is NOT www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$
# 301 redirect to the same resource on www.domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I keep trying to understand the syntax of the htaccess redirect and all, but It's really weird, do you know of a good place to learn that? thanks again!

Comment: Also sometimes I see that people would write things differently on the last square brackets, like : [R=permanent,QSA,L] what's the difference?

Comment: See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html.  301 is a permanent redirect.  `QSA` means _append the existing query string onto the rewritten URL, but that happens automatically for a `[R]` redirect so I omitted it as redundant.  `[L]` means _don't process any other matching rules_ and is needed if you have more rules that may match the input URL.

Comment: Otherwise, I just [refer to the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and work from experience.  The docs don't have great examples -- I think I've mostly just learned from experience.