# htaccess redirect alias to main domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i am trying to redirect from alias domain to main domain for every possible url. I am using htaccess to make my urls more beautiful. This is my example and code I have so far:

Desired outpout:

```
Alias page: www.stavimedumsvepomoci.cz/forum.html
gets redirected to the main domain: www.stavbadomusvepomoci.cz/forum.html
```

Now I need this to work for every possible url I can have after the .cz/

So far I have this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?stavimedumsvepomoci\.cz [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://stavbadomusvepomoci.cz/$1 [R,L]
```

Which basically redirects any page from the alias to the main domain front page.
How can I redirect from alias/every/possible/url to maindomain/every/possible/url.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: You do already this: $1 permits to do it, alias/every/possible/url to maindomain/every/possible/url. Have you tested it?

Comment: well, i'll be damned,.. it was not working when i tried that and it is working now,.. thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the comments, You do already this: $1 permits to do it, alias/every/possible/url to maindomain/every/possible/url. Have you tested it?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?stavimedumsvepomoci\.cz [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://stavbadomusvepomoci.cz/$1 [R,L]
```

Hope you succeed.

[ADDED]

You might have done:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: as noted above,.. thank you very much. Not sure why it was not working. I am glad it is now..