# Remove Plesk preview domain redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, plesk

Plesk offers you a handy way to preview the site before you switch over the DNS, called [Websites Preview](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP10/10.4/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-administrator-guide/index.htm?fileName=70219.htm).

This is what it does:

> customer-site.tld will be available for preview as customer-site.tld.192-0-2-12.your-domain.tld. Here 192-0-2-12 is the site's IP where dots are replaced with dashes

I find this feature very useful, as we use it for proofing websites before they go live, however after the site goes live the `customer-site.tld.192-0-2-12.your-domain.tld` URL still exists, and is showing up in some Google results!

How can I remove the preview URL for certain sites only, not for all sites on the server?

Alternatively I think I may be able to use a .htaccess rule for this, but I cannot figure out how to do that without a redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this with some more searching (I searched for how to redirect domain alias, as that's what this essentially is).

The answer is here: [Redirecting all domain aliases to one with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248788/redirecting-all-domain-aliases-to-one-with-htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine On
# If the hostname is NOT www.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$
# 301 redirect to the same resource on www.domain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Remember to remove the 'www' if the site is non-www, to prevent redirect loops.

Answer (score 0):

Use [robots.txt](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156449?hl=en) file to prevent crawlers from indexing your page. After you have done DNS switching, remove robots.txt file

Comment: I can't use robots.txt as this is an alias of the domain, not a separate host.